# The countdown timer is not working properly when I insert few numbers such as 31,41,51,61

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I want to show a countdown timer using JavaScript. However when I insert the current value to be 31,41,51,99,61,81 and few other numbers I am unable to get the Arc based on the inserted current value. The Arc should display the current value. As the number gets reducing, closer to Zero, the Arc should keep moving towards completing the circle.

I tried using HTML5 Canvas, I almost close to getting the answer but it's throwing some error.

The fields should have Maximum Value input text field and Current Value text field and a button which on clicked should display the Current Value Arc inside Canvas Element. Please help

```js
         <!-- Click event function, works when button is clicked -->
         function clickevent()
         {
         var max=document.getElementById("maxsec").value;
         var curr=document.getElementById("currsec").value;  
         myFunction(max,curr);
         }
         //This is the 
        function myFunction(maxvalue,currentvalue) {
            //alert(maxvalue + ' ' + currentvalue);
            if (currentvalue<=maxvalue)
            { 
            var x =   (2*3.14*currentvalue/maxvalue);
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.font="15px Georgia";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";     
        ctx.fillText(currentvalue,c.width/2, c.height/2); 
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(75, 75, 50, x, 2 * Math.PI);
              // ctx.lineWidth = 10;
              // line color
              ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
              ctx.stroke();
        }
        if (maxvalue==currentvalue)
        {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.font="15px Georgia";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";     
        ctx.fillText("Time Up",c.width/2, c.height/2);
        ctx.textAlign="center";
        }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <div>
        Max Second: <input type="text" id="maxsec" value="300"><br/>
        Current Second: <input type="text" id="currsec" value="150">
        <button onclick="clickevent()">Click me</button>
        <br/>
       //This is the canvas section where the Arc or the curvature will            be displayed.
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px       solid #d3d3d3;">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I don't see any timer function in your code. Do you have it somewhere else?

Comment: I have not used timer function I just want to display the current value in the Arc based on the Max Value. Below is the javascript code

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the values as a `string` into the function instead of `number`, if you change the below lines of code, it works fine!

**JS:**

```
var max=parseInt(document.getElementById("maxsec").value);
var curr=parseInt(document.getElementById("currsec").value);  
myFunction(max,curr);
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Please use this attempt of making your timer using `setTimeout()` function as a reference and build your code!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>